# Пропала панель компонентов в VS 2018. Как ее включить?

Tags: visual-studio

Создал новое приложение `C#` `winForms` открыл конструктор формы, а на панели элементов нет вкладки с визуальными компонентами.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как ее можно включить? Перезапуск студии пробовал не помогло.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нажмите **Ctrl + Alt + X** или **View -> Toolbox**

Answer (score 0):

Зайдите в Вид->Изменить в VisualStudio. Появится новое окно проекта с панелью элементов.